# Synthesize error in std_logic_vector to integer conversion [ERRORS: HDLParsers: 854]

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise

```
count := to_integer( unsigned ( values(i)));
```

**Error:**
    ERRORS: HDLParsers: 854 - The expression can not be converted to type unsigned

**Preconditions:**

- imports

  ```
  library ieee;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
  use ieee.math_real.all;
  ```
- count declared as

  ```
  variable count : integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
  ```
- values declared as

  ```
  values: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  ```
- Assignement operator <= tested without success yet.

Answer (score 0):

`values(i)` is of type `std_logic`. You cannot type cast an `std_logic` into an `unsigned`. This seems like an odd thing to be doing, perhaps if you could explain why you are trying to do this, I could provide an alternative.

Comment: this passage is included into a process which operates as BCD converter. I want to convert the binary input (`std_logic_vector`) into a integer variable (`count`) with a for loop, considering one bit per loop and adding its decimal value on the variable count iteratively. It would be something like this, but we were just doing some tests:
`count := count + to_integer(unsigned(values(i)))*(2**i)`

Comment: @DavidePimpinella maybe it would be worth adding your whole `process` to the question. Alternatively, there are many existing questions on binary to BCD conversion.